# TouchableOpacity highlighting when scroll inside Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity, touchablehighlight

[image]

I have TouchableOpacity rendered inside the row item of Flatlist. I wanted to show a click effect when user click on the item. However, the click effect also triggered when user start scrolling. How can I disable the highlighting effect when user is scrolling?

Comment: can you try `TouchableWithoutFeedback` with `delayPressIn` prop instead of `TouchableOpacity`

Comment: with delayPressIn, I can somehow disable the highlighting effect when scrolling, but when I click on the item, item won't be highlighted immediately due to the delay.. so I guess it is not the optimum solution..

Comment: That can be tweaked by changing the `delayPressIn` value i guess. What value you given?

Comment: I was setting to 50

Comment: try some low value as see because scroll touch on screen wont last long

Comment: a tap on the screen is fast enough as well.. so setting a lower delay time doesn't solve the issue

Comment: I have the same issue ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable highlighting effect of TouchableOpacity when scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421283/how-to-disable-highlighting-effect-of-touchableopacity-when-scrolling)