# How to disable highlighting effect of TouchableOpacity when scrolling?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, touchableopacity

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1 }} >
  <ImageBackground
    source={require('../../images/home.jpg')}>
      <View style={styles.item} collapsable={false}>
        <H3>{contentData[i].name}</H3>
        <Text>{contentData[i].description}</Text>
      </View>
  </ImageBackground>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I have a list of `TouchableOpacity` inside a `ScrollView`. I want to **disable highlighting effect** of `TouchableOpacity`. When scrolling I want to highlight only when `onPress` event is triggered. Because it may confuse the user that it is pressed.

Answer (score 57):

Simply pass `activeOpactity` prop with value 1.

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}>....</TouchableOpacity>
```

Make sure you import TouchableOpacity from "react-native" not from "react-native-gesture-handler".

Comment: I'm confused--why use TouchableOpacity if you set the element's opacity to 1 when the user interacts with it? Isn't the whole goal to indicate user interactions by changing the opacity?

Comment: @duhaime honestly speaking the default effect looks so weird sometimes that developer wants to get rid of it entirely. At the end, there will be UX loss either way. Sometimes, removing that effect seems better option.

Comment: @JeevanPrakash then you should use TouchableWithoutFeedback

Comment: @Will I would have to disagree because I am using a conditionally pressable component (it can be pressable or not) so it is much easier to do something like this `activeOpacity={isPressable ? 0.2 : 1}`

Answer (score 16):

Try setting the `activeOpacity` prop on the `TouchableOpacity` to 1 when scrolling. Use default settings when the user stops scrolling.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity#activeopacity

Comment: This works fine. Thanks! Setting activeOpacity={1} does not fade the view.

Comment: you can decrease the value if you want a lighter fade effect

Answer (score 11):

You can try changing param **delayPressIn**. [Look doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#delaypressin).

```
<TouchableOpacity delayPressIn={150} > 
 {children}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: work like a charm. but i prefer using 100 ms delay time as the fade effect won't show on scroll but still visible on normal press

Comment: Please do not use this tip, It is a hard workaround. Prefer use `activeOpacity={1}`

Answer (score 5):

You could try replace **TouchOpacity** with **RectButton** in **'react-native-gesture-handler'**. And don't forget to replace the **ScrollView** import from **'react-native'** to **'react-native-gesture-handler'**.

I found this solution in [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/component-buttons.html).

It just said:

> **provides native and platform default interaction for buttons that are placed in a scrollable container (in which case the interaction is slightly delayed to prevent button from highlighting when you fling)**

Comment: The documentation link has updated. It's now here: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/components/buttons/

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [`onScrollBeginDrag`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscrollenddrag) and [`onScrollEndDrag`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onscrollenddrag) props.

```
 state = {
    scrollBegin: false
  }

  scrollStart = () => this.setState({scrollBegin: true})   
  scrollEnd = () => this.setState({scrollBegin: false})

 <ScrollView onScrollBeginDrag={this.scrollStart} onScrollEndDrag={this.scrollEnd}>
   ... Other stuff
 </ScrollView>
```

and set [`activeOpacity={1}`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity#activeopacity) for TouchableOpacity when `this.state.scrollBegin=true`

Comment: Thank you @Pritish Vaidya but it doesn't solve my problem. Your solution is worked after scrolling is started but not the moment i started scroll.

Answer (score 4):

We implemeted a custom **Touchable** component using **TouchableOpacity** as click element and a wrapper **View** handling the opacity of the children elements.

By setting **activeOpacity={1}** to default and the **pressed** state to true when clicking, we can delay the rest of the onPress functionality by a unnoticeable 100ms to display an opacity shift when clicking. Which is shipped to the wrapper **View**. The View is wrapped inside the touchable instead of outside to better preserve styling.

We also added cleanup when component is unmounted in **useEffect()**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";


const Touchable = (props) => {

  const { children, onPress } = props;

  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    return setPressed(false);
  }, []);

  return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        {...props}
        activeOpacity={1}
        onPress={() => {
          setPressed(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setPressed(false);
            onPress();
          }, 100);
        }}
      >
        <View style={{opacity: pressed ? 0.8 : 1}}>
        {children}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

  );
};
export default Touchable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so I wrote this class that I use instead of <**TouchableOpacity**> in my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';

class TouchableOpacityScrollable extends Component {
  _onPress() {
    const { onPress } = this.props;

    // Looking in the TouchableOpacity source code we see that
    // the touch Opacity is 150, and that it comes back in 250 milliseconds.
    // @see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c416b40542ece64e26fb2298485ae42eeebc352a/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js
    this.refs.touchableOpacity.setOpacityTo(0.2, 150);

    TimerMixin.setTimeout(() => {
      onPress();
      this.refs.touchableOpacity.setOpacityTo(1, 250);
    }, 150);
  }

  render() {
    const { style, children } = this.props;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        ref="touchableOpacity"
        style={style}
        activeOpacity={1.0}
        onPress={() => this._onPress()}
      >
        {children}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default TouchableOpacityScrollable;
```

You will have to install [react-timer-mixin](https://github.com/reactjs/react-timer-mixin)  to prevent [possible crashes](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers#timermixin).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

after upgrading RN version to 0.63.2 TouchableOpacity is working like it should, during scrolling, hover effect doesn't appears

Comment: I'm on 0.63.3 and it doesn't just work out of the box :s

Comment: I'm on 67.4 and having the same issue